# Can someone help me fix the bottom two rows of my nested loop? They shouldn't be the same lengths, but they are

Tags: function, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-for-loop

I'm working on a project where I'd like to create the following pattern:

```
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
```

.. and so forth. There are twenty rows in all, and the twentieth row should have 20 X's. Here is what I came up with that's so close:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="xloop();">Accept</button> <br>
<p id="xloops"></p>

<script>
function xloop() {
let text = "";
for (j=2; j<=20; j++) {
text+= ("X") + ("<br>");
for (k=1; k<j; k++) {
text += ("X");
}
}
document.getElementById("xloops").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The pattern begins appropriately and does what I want until the very last row. The 20th row only has 19 elements in it, rather than the necessary 20. I have a feeling that this has to do with the "j<k" piece in the k loop being strictly less than j when j equals 20, but any other trial and error combination of indices or inequalities hasn't worked.. is there a way I can remedy this situation using this kind of solution alone without any added complexity?

Comment: Each piece of text that you generate consists of one `X`, a `<br>`, and then j-1 `X`s.  I have no idea why you did it that way - don't you want the line break at the end of the line?

Comment: Honestly, when it comes to For loops, I find them really confusing. I don't really quite know what I'm doing yet. This is just kind of a desperate attempt to make things work. lol.

It was recommended to me to use the padStart feature and set something up like str.padStart(i,"X") in the loop, but any kind of use of that command broke everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will help you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="xloop()">Accept</button> <br>
    <p id="xloops"></p>
    <script>
        function xloop() {
            let text = "";
            for (let j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                let text2 = "";
                for (let k = 0; k <= j; k++) {
                    //row
                    text2 += "X"; 
                }
                //line
                text += `${text2}` + "<br>"
            }
            document.getElementById("xloops").innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you! Appreciate you understanding my mess here lol. Have a great weekend!

Comment: You have a great weekend too